# SaveOrUpdate in NHibernate : id is 0 for relater entities

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactions, entity, uniqueidentifier

I have entity `Listing` and `ListingForLease` (short version)

```
public class Listing: Entity{//some properties}
public class ListingForLease: Listing
{
    public ListingForLease()
    {
        ListingSpaces = new HashedSet<ListingSpace>();
    }

    public virtual ISet<ListingSpace> ListingSpaces { get; set; }
}
```

And entity ListingSpace :

```
public class ListingSpace : Entity
{
    public ListingSpace(){        }
    public virtual ListingForLease ListingForLease{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual double Size { get; set; }
}
```

`Entity` is from [SharpArch](http://sharparchitecture.net/) Architectural foundation, so it gives my own entities field `Id`.

For Mapping To database I used NHibernate.
Listing mapping :

```
<class name="Listing" table="bt_listing" >

    <id name="Id" column="Id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <!-- JOINED SUBCLASSES -->

    <!-- listing for lease -->
    <joined-subclass name="ListingForLease" table="bt_listing_for_lease" proxy="ListingForLease" lazy="true">
        <key column="Id" />
        <property name="PropertyName" column="property_name" />
        ....
        <set name="ListingSpaces" table="bt_listing_space" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key column="listing_for_lease_id" />
            <one-to-many class="ListingSpace" />
        </set>
    </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

Listing Space mapping :

```
<class name="ListingSpace" table="bt_listing_space" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id" column="listing_space_id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <many-to-one name="ListingForLease" class="ListingForLease" column="listing_for_lease_id" cascade="save-update" />

    <property name="Name" column="[name]" />
    <property name="Size" column = "size" />

</class>
```

---

Problem : When i create new `listing` and make `_listingRepository.SaveOrUpdate((Listing)listing);` then I can get from new listing `id`'s of also new spaces.

But when I only update listing (add new spaces) I can't get `id`'s of added spaces (`id` is equal to 0). Added spaces are saved only after commiting transaction `_listingRepository.DbContext.CommitTransaction();`

This problem is in my mappings or this is usual behaviour of NHibernate?

---

**UPDATE :**  adding new space (from viewModel)

```
listing = EntityMapHelper
    //map some data to ListingForLease entity
    .MapListingForLeaseToEntity((ListingForLeaseViewModel)model,(ListingForLease)listing, locationDictionary, brokerList);      

var listingForLease = (ListingForLeaseViewModel)model;
var listingSpacesToRemove = new List<ListingForLeaseSpace>();
//edit existing spaces
((ListingForLease)listing).ListingSpaces
    .Where(s => !s.IsDeleted).ToList()
    .ForEach(s =>
    {
        var editedSpace = listingForLease.Spaces.FirstOrDefault(es => es.SpaceId == s.Id);
        if (editedSpace != null)
        {
            s.Name = editedSpace.Name;
            s.Size = editedSpace.Size.GetValueOrDefault(0);
            // here must go other mappings for fields
        }
        else
        {
            if (s.HasRelatedRecs)
            {
                s.IsDeleted = true;
            }
            else
            {
                listingSpacesToRemove.Add(s);
            }
        }
    });


//remove deleted spaces
((ListingForLease)listing).ListingSpaces.RemoveAll(listingSpacesToRemove);
//add new spaces
((ListingForLease) listing)
    .ListingSpaces
    .AddAll(listingForLease.Spaces
    .Where(s => s.SpaceId == 0).ToList()
    .Select(s =>
    {
        var retEntity =
            new ListingSpace
            {
                ListingForLease = ((ListingForLease) listing),
                Name = s.Name,
                //other fields
            };

        return retEntity;

    }).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, that the essential part is here:

```
<class name="Listing"  ... >
...
    <set name="ListingSpaces" table="bt_listing_space" lazy="true" 
             inverse="true"                // here
             cascade="all-delete-orphan">  
       <key column="listing_for_lease_id" />
       <one-to-many class="ListingSpace" />
    </set>
```

The collection is mapped as **inverse**. That means, that if you experience:

> *... But when i only update listing (add new spaces) i can't get id's of added spaces (id is equal to 0)...*

The most suspected is, that the item added into collection, does not know about its parent. So this must be the proper code to profit from **`inverse="true"`**:

```
// get Listing.... existing one
var existingListing = ... // GetExistingSomehow(); 
// new space
var space = new ListingSpace ();
// must have assigned parent. MUST
space.Listing = existingListing;
// parnet colleciton is extended
existingListing.ListingSpaces.Add(space);
// save just parent, cascade will do the rest
session.SaveOrUpdate(existingListing);
```

So, if inverse is in play... we must not forget to assign both ends. Both are *must* to let NHibernate behave properly...

EXTEND:

In case that the issue is: when updating *parent* `Listing`, all newly added items `ListingSpace` do have their own ID equal to 0 - until the Commit is called: it is absolutely OK.

NHibernate does work with abstraction called ISession. It is not immediately persisted into underlying DB. Check the [9.6. Flush](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing). If we want ID's, generated by DB engine (generator="native") to be assigned, we can anytime call explicit

```
session.Flush();
```

which will properly write all changes made in sesion in correct order into DB.

Comment: thanks for reply. I check it and must to say that my new space knows about its parent.

Comment: Could you show the code you use to add new spaces to existing listing?

Comment: What are black boxes to me is `MapListingForLeaseToEntity` which returns listing. Is listing after that properly initiated? Also `AddAll` could be converting passed items into some new isntances without parent...

Comment: `MapListingForLeaseToEntity `- this method return properly initiated listing. I checked all spaces just before step `SaveOrUpdate` and every space has proper parent

Comment: Wait a second, what is your problem? That spaces have their own ID equal to 0 - before the Commit is called? But that is normal, absolutely ok. The trick is that your Commit triggers the Flush. And before that... id is equal to its defualt value. Other words, if you want to get the Ids of the space items... before comit, just call `session.Flush()`... does it help?

Comment: well using Flush make sense for me now. I will try and write you. Thanks